# Как включить ЧПУ в компоненте news.list битрикс

Tags: php, .htaccess, битрикс

На сайте есть папка inform в ней 2 файла index.php и detail.php
В файле index.php вызывается компонент news.list, в файле detail.php вызывается компонент news.detail. В файле index.php если задано DETAIL_URL=/inform/detail.php?ELEMENT_CODE=#ELEMENT_CODE# детальная новость выводится, если ничего не задано или задано DETAIL_URL=/inform/#ELEMENT_CODE#/ детальная новость не выводится вместо нее пустая белая страница ошибок на ней нет. Пробовал использовать вместо news.list компонент news тоже самое получается.

Как изменить DETAIL_URL, чтобы детальная страница отображалась и URL имел вид /inform/frukty/ ????????

Привожу коды компонентов и код файла urlrewrite.php

Код файла index.php в папке inform

```html
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
?><h1>Информация</h1>
<div class="tile">
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.list", "inform_l", array(
 "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "cont",
 "IBLOCK_ID" => "3",
 "NEWS_COUNT" => "100",
 "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
 "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
 "SORT_BY2" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
 "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
 "FILTER_NAME" => "",
 "FIELD_CODE" => array(
  0 => "NAME",
  1 => "",
 ),
 "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
  0 => "",
  1 => "",
 ),
 "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
 "DETAIL_URL" => "/inform/detail.php?ELEMENT_CODE=#ELEMENT_CODE#",
 "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
 "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
 "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
 "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
 "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
 "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",
 "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
 "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.y G:i",
 "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
 "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
 "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
 "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
 "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
 "PARENT_SECTION" => "4",
 "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
 "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TITLE" => "Информация",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
 "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "pagenav",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_DATE" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => ""
 ),
 false
);?>
</div>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Код файла detail.php в папке inform

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Заголовок");
?><?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.detail", "inform_detail", array(
 "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "cont",
 "IBLOCK_ID" => "3",
 "ELEMENT_ID" => $_REQUEST["ID"],
 "ELEMENT_CODE" => $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_CODE"],
 "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
 "FIELD_CODE" => array(
  0 => "",
  1 => "",
 ),
 "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
  0 => "",
  1 => "",
 ),
 "IBLOCK_URL" => "",
 "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
 "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
 "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
 "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
 "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
 "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
 "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
 "BROWSER_TITLE" => "SEO_T",
 "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
 "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
 "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
 "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
 "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
 "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "inform_detail",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
 "USE_SHARE" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => ""
 ),
 false
);?> <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Код файла urlrewrite.php

```html
<?
$arUrlRewrite = array(
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/inform/([^/]+)/($|\\?.*)#",
  "RULE" => "ELEMENT_CODE=$1",
  "ID" => "",
  "PATH" => "/inform/detail.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/inform/#",
  "RULE" => "bitrix:news.list",
  "ID" => "",
  "PATH" => "/inform/index.php",
 )
);

?>
```

Код шаблона info_list

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<ul>
<?/*if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
 <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br />
<?endif;*/?>
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
 <?
 $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
 $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
 ?>

   <li><a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></a></li>

<?endforeach;?>
<?/*if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
 <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
<?endif;*/?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашей реализации, с тем что уже сделано можно сделать так:

- в файле urlrewrite.php наверно не то что то, вот пример

вместо этого:

```
array(
    "CONDITION" =>  "#^/inform/([^/]+)/($|\\?.*)#",
    "RULE"  =>  "ELEMENT_CODE=$1",
    "ID"    =>  "",
    "PATH"  =>  "/inform/detail.php",
),
```

попробуйте так (т. е. выбирается из урла вторая часть после /inform/ который может быть символами и цифрами, и то что найдено будет передано в файл /inform/detail.php в $_REQUEST[‘ELEMENT_CODE’], а в этом файле вы уже будете использовать где хотите  ):

```
array ( 
    'CONDITION' => '#^/inform/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?(.*)#',
    'RULE' => 'ELEMENT_CODE=$1',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/inform/detail.php',
),
```

- В файле index.php укажите DETAIL_URL = "/inform/#ELEMENT_CODE#" (тогда урлы в шаблоне будут составлены такого типа , /inform/<код элемента> )
- а в файле detail.php уберите строчку "ELEMENT_ID" => $_REQUEST["ID"] (ведь Вы же не собираетесь передавать id товара да и в файле urlrewrite.php такой вариант не описали, а в этом файле у вас будет код элемента из урла в переменной $_REQUEST[‘ELEMENT_CODE’] которую вы уже подкидываете в компонент )

Но потестируйте может чуть другая регулярка нужна (можно найти в документации).

Если белый экран то надо включить в битриксе вывод php ошибок.

(Ну наверно проще было бы комплексный компонент использовать news - по нему много статей и документации)